# Difference between "Wie geht es dir?" and "Wie kommst du voran?"

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context, phrase

Related: [Alternatives to "Wie geht es dir?"](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/17192/43989) . Apparently both "Wie geht es dir?" and "Wie kommst du voran?" can be translated as "How's it going?" From the dictionary meanings I gather that the second one relates more to progress on a task or work, while the first is more about general conditions or well-being. Is this correct?

Context: I'm taking a stab at watching a let's play of Kingdom Come Deliverance in German. The game is set in the middle ages and the wife of a blacksmith is returning home late morning after running errands in the village. She asks her husband who is busily working at the forge, "Wie kommst du voran?". In the English version she asks "How goes it?" from which I was expecting some variation on "Wie geht es dir?" in the German version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

"Wie geht es dir?" = "How are you doing?"

"Wie kommst du voran?" = "How are you making progress?"

Answer (score 2):

"Wie geht es dir?" is very general and – speaking in terms of sociopragmatics – unmarked.

"Wie kommst du voran?" presupposes that the asker knows something about the askee and their endeavours, be they small, e.g., "Wie kommst du voran [mit der Hausaufgabe]?", or large, e.g., "Wie kommst du voran [mit dem Studium]?". Since it involves a presupposition, sometimes it's unclear what exactly is being referred to and it could concern any or all of the askee's ongoing projects.